# Can i install Integration Runtime in Azure Virtual Machine and add on-prem server as linked services?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-data-factory

I want to pull data from on-prem to azure data lake gen2 using Azure Data Factory. I have installed an Integration runtime in my local system and added an on-prem server as a linked server to Integration Runtime and was able to pull data successfully.

Now I want to install Integration Runtime in Azure Virtual Machine and add my on-prem server as a Linked service and pull data.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) where it says

> The installation of a self-hosted integration runtime needs an
> on-premises machine or a virtual machine inside a private network.

So the answer is yes. But the VM needs to be inside your network. In other words, your on prem network needs to extended to the cloud and the VM needs to be deployed on this.

Comment: In other words, do you have site-to-site VPN or ExpressRoute setup? Can you connect from the Azure VM to on prem?

Comment: @GregGalloway Is correct. VPN or express route is required.